# SimpleXMLElement::xpath dont diferintiate between number as string

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have xml with tags like the below:

```
<tag id="02220">
<tag id="2220">
```

When I search for example on:

```
Xml->xpath('//tag [@id='."2220".']');
```

The result will be an array of both ids. How to let xpath treat them as string?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the quotes around the value you are looking for, currently your query comes out as

```
echo '//tag[@id='."2220".']';
```

gives

```
//tag[@id=2220]
```

as you can see, it is a number.  Add quotes round the field...

```
echo '//tag[@id="'."2220".'"]';
```

will give you

```
//tag[@id="2220"]
```